# getActiveUser().getEmail() not working with Multiple users

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with input form and need a information of user email when any user use input form.

I found script such as " Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); "

It works well and I can get data with email information on sheet when the owner of sheet run the input form. But not when someone else. I can not get email of others.
Do you know what the problem is?

```
function onOpen(e){
   var emailName = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
   Logger.log(emailName);
  return emailName;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should be using an installable trigger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() results are inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664758/session-getactiveuser-getemail-results-are-inconsistent)

Comment: Related [getActiveUser() doesn't return the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57847178/1595451)

Comment: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() will return a user if the logged in user is within your G Suite domain